# DropDown list selected value is not displaying after page refresh it shows first value in jsp java

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

what i want is

1. I have a Dropdown List when I select Dropdown value click Get button it will display table rows in database based on dropdown value selection.

My problem is:

2.In my application, Here when i select first value clicking button it will display values in table but when i select second value from dropdown it shows only initially first value in dropdown it not showing which value is selected from dropdown

Here i am Images:
[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZp9G.png)

Code:

```
Users : <select name="ddlPoster" style="height: 20px;width: 170px" >          
            <%  rs = st.executeQuery(ddl); while (rs.next()){%>
            <option value="<%=rs.getString("ID")%>"><%=rs.getString("UserId")%><%}%> </select>
            <br/><br/>
            <button type="submit" onclick="myfunction()">Submit</button><br/><br/>

 <table  align="left" id="tbldisplay" >  
 <tr>
                          <th>#</th>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Poster</th>
                          <th>ChargeType</th>
 </tr>
  <%     
  String Poster=request.getParameter("ddlPoster"); 
  if(Poster !=null){
      String query="select * from Details where user=(select userid from users where id='"+Poster+"')";
      ResultSet re = st.executeQuery(query);   
         while(re.next()){
     %>

<tr><td></td>
    <td><%=re.getString(1)%><td>
    <td><%=re.getString(2)%></td>
     <td><%=re.getString(3)%></td>
     <td><%=re.getString(4)%></td>  
     </tr>
<%
}}}
catch(Exception e){}
%>
</table>
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the response from database when you select 2nd option from drop down menu? did you print it for debug?

Comment: when i select second value to display data in table the dropdown value shows what is the first value in list it goes to same value